# Getting comparison between ! and user input

Tags: c++

I'm not sure why this is causing me trouble, I think I did it earlier in a test and it worked fine.

I get some user input using `cin` then pass this to another method as a char. I then just wanted to say:

```
if(userInput == '!'){
     //do Something
}
```

But it didn't get it, so I tried defining a char as:

```
const char myChar ='\u033f';


if(guess == myChar){
    exit(0);

}
```

But this just gives me a few compile errors even thou I'm getting that from another StackOverflow thread.

I must be misunderstanding something fundamental here, could someone enlighten me?

TIA

Comment: use `strcmp` to compare strings

Comment: What compiler errors are you getting?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: He's not comparing strings, he is comparing `char`s... or so he says.

Comment: Unicode char literals are only supported in C++11. Your compiler might probably not support that yet. As for your _actual_ problem, how are you getting the input?

Comment: You can't do a direct comparison between two strings unless they're both single chars. You do this: `if(chr1[0] == chr2[0])` but you can't compare between two char arrays or strings, since they're technically pointers. If you want to compare a string, use strcmp.

Comment: @Gogeta70: He *is* comparing a against a char, not a `char*`.  That said, we do not see how he is declaring `userInput`.

Comment: Please post a **short**, **complete** program that demonstrates the problem you are having. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: @EdS. I know that one of the parameters he's comparing against is a char, but i'm assuming that UserInput is either an array or a char pointer, since the comparison should be working otherwise.

Comment: @Gogeta70 Do not assume anything until the question is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example works for me:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const char myChar = '!';
    char guess;
    std::cin >> guess;
    if (guess == myChar) {
        exit(0);
    }
    std::cerr << "No!" << std::endl;
}
```

Perhaps if your question is clarified a little more, I can edit this answer to be a little more complete.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this works for me, so I think your problem is in an area that you have not posted.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char c;
    cin >> c;

    if( c == '!' )
        cout << "Worked!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Something else..." << endl;    
}
```

So, now that we've proven the most basic example works, how about showing us more code?  Show us how you declare `userInput` and where you read in, i.e., a full working (or rather, non-working...) code sample.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me and will capture an exclamation mark.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char a;
    if(std::cin >> a && a=='!')
        std::cout << "! received" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @EdS.I aren't the best typer. :(